# Better way to edit complex UIs than using IB

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, interface-builder

For **simple UIs, IB is a great tool** to edit controls and outlets.

If **UIs get more complex** and contain many bindings, things tend to get **opaque**. At one side, you edit source code, at the other side, you edit XIBs. Xcode's search feature finds certain names in XIB, but not all. For example, Xcode doesn't find properties of bindings in XIBs.

Thus, I wonder, if better ways to edit UIs exist.

If UIs could be - optionally - specified using XML, one could easily search and replace all occurrences of a given name [or even dynamically generate XML specifications].

I feel Adobe Flex' UI editor - either visual or using the nicely integrated XML-editor - combines both worlds in a good way: The XML-editor is fully aware of defined names and provides a helpful auto-completer.

**How should complex UIs be managed using Xcode?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have the option of examining/editing the nib files directly using the command line tools like [ibtool.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html) I use it at times to inspect complex bindings.

Beyond the graphical editors, Xcode and even Interface Builder are really just faces for a collection unix command line tools. You can always dig as far under the hood as you wish.

Nib files are just plist files which are just a specific xml schema so you can edit them directly if you wish. However, they are much more complex than Flex files for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 3):

IB has a lot of problems. It's also still the best tool for the job in most cases. (The same can be said of Xcode generally.) As much as possible, keep your nib files simple and avoid really fancy or complex bindings.

If you find cases where Xcode's Refactor...Rename tool does not correctly modify nib files, you should open a bug at bugreport.apple.com.